# Creating a Basic Java phone book

Tags: java

I'm just learning Java and trying to make a simple phone book. For this part I'm trying to prompt the user to choose one of the 3 options below.

```
public class PhoneBook {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        options();      
        /*This method prompts the user to enter phone number
        String s;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Phone Number");
        s = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered phone number ");
        System.out.println(s);*/
    }

    public static void options (){
    //This method gives the user choices on what to do

        char choice;
        char enterNumber = 'n';
        char showNumber = 's';
        char closeBook = 'c';

        String read;
        String freeLine = "error";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true){

            System.out.println("Please select from the following");
            System.out.println("n to Enter the number");
            System.out.println("s to Show the number ");
            System.out.println("c to Close the Phone book");

        read = keyboard.nextLine(); 
        choice = read.charAt(0);
        switch (choice) {
        case 'n': enterNumber; 
                system.out.println();
        case 's':showNumber;
                system.out.println();
        case 'c': closeBook;
                    break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid Entry");


        } 
        }
    }

}
```

When I compile it i get errors on lines 37, 39, and 41 saying "Error: not a statement". I feel like something is missing. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line is line 37?

Comment: what do you expect `case 's':showNumber;` to do?

Comment: I don't understand how this is a phonebook. It seems to me to be some kind of 'enter something and print it' or 'echo' duplicate.

Comment: It should also be `System.out.println();` not `system.out.println();` - Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: @njzk2 the case 's':showNumber; is supposed to be the option for someone the see the number they just typed in.

Comment: @ifly6 yes, it's the beggining, it 's not the finished phonebook. It's just like you said all I want the person to be able to do at this point is choice from the selection; "n" to input new number, "s" to show number they just typed, or "c" to close the program if they are done.

Comment: @Jesper ok thanx :)

Comment: `case 's':` ok, but what is `showNumber;` for? that is not a statement.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that with the following lines you want to achieve to print the letter `n` for `enterNumber` in the console?

```
case 'n': enterNumber; 
          system.out.println();
```

This is not correct Java syntax. You will have to **pass the variable value** to the `System.out.println` method call:

```
case 'n': System.out.println(enterNumber);
```

Also note that Java is case sensitive, so you have to spell `System` with a capital letter.

On a side note, you will want to `break;` after each of your `case` statements, otherwise the code of the following cases will be executed as well:

```
switch (choice) {
    case 'n': System.out.println(enterNumber);
              break;
    case 's': System.out.println(showNumber);
              break;
    case 'c': System.out.println(closeBook);
              break;
    default: System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
}
```

Comment: I did run it and it just keeps duplicating the choices. Like when I select a choice for example i put in "n". It's supposed to give me a blank line so I can enter the number, but instead it's just repeating the choices text.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to write variable after 'cast' statement.

Refer below code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneBook {


    public static void main (String[] args){
        options();      
        /*This method prompts the user to enter phone number
        String s;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Phone Number");
        s = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered phone number ");
        System.out.println(s);*/
    }

    public static void options (){
    //This method gives the user choices on what to do

        char choice;
        char enterNumber = 'n';
        char showNumber = 's';
        char closeBook = 'c';

        String read;
        String freeLine = "error";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true){

            System.out.println("Please select from the following");
            System.out.println("n to Enter the number");
            System.out.println("s to Show the number ");
            System.out.println("c to Close the Phone book");

        read = keyboard.nextLine(); 
        choice = read.charAt(0);
        switch (choice) {
        case 'n':  
        System.out.println();
        case 's':
        System.out.println();
        case 'c': 
                    break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid Entry");


        } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no "cast" on their code. And your code only prints blank new lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a special answer for you. I don't add additional explanation. It's a large answer. I tell more than you ask, but I've done my best to make a readable code, so that you can analyse step-by-step to understand what you need at least when trying to make a Phone Book (console test drive application). If you need more explanation, write under comments.

**First make a `PhoneEntry` class:**

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class PhoneEntry implements Comparable<PhoneEntry> {
    // https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%2C%7D((-%7C%5Cs)%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%2C%7D)*%24
    private static final String NAME_PATTERN = "^[a-zA-Z]{2,}((\\-|\\s)[a-zA-Z]{2,})*$";

    // https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5E%5C%2B%3F%5Cd%2B((%5Cs%7C%5C-)%3F%5Cd%2B)%2B%24
    private static final String NUMBER_PATTERN = "^\\+?\\d+((\\s|\\-)?\\d+)+$"; //^\+?\d+((\s|\-)?\d+)+$

    private final String name;
    private final String number;

    public PhoneEntry(String name, String number) {
        if (!name.matches(NAME_PATTERN) || !number.matches(NUMBER_PATTERN)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public boolean nameContainsIgnoreCase(String keyword) {
        return (keyword != null)
                ? name.toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase())
                : true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof PhoneEntry)) {
            return false;
        }
        PhoneEntry phoneEntry = (PhoneEntry) obj;
        return name.equalsIgnoreCase(phoneEntry.name)
                && number.equalsIgnoreCase(phoneEntry.number);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name.toLowerCase());
        hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.number.toLowerCase());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PhoneEntry phoneEntry) {
        return name.compareToIgnoreCase(phoneEntry.name);
    }
}
```

---

**Then the test drive**

```
public class TestDrive {

    private static final String choices = "nspc";

    enum Choice {
        CREATE, READ, PRINT, CLOSE;

        static Choice getChoice(char c) {
            switch (c) {
                case 'n':
                    return Choice.CREATE;
                case 's':
                    return Choice.READ;
                case 'p':
                    return Choice.PRINT;
                case 'c':
                    return Choice.CLOSE;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        final Set<PhoneEntry> entries = new TreeSet<>();
        Choice choice;
        while ((choice = getChoice(kbd)) != Choice.CLOSE) {
            switch (choice) {
                case CREATE:
                    PhoneEntry entry = getPhoneEntry(kbd);
                    if (entry != null) {
                        entries.add(entry);
                    }
                    break;
                case READ:
                    print(readEntries(entries, kbd));
                    break;
                case PRINT:
                    print(entries);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static Choice getChoice(Scanner kbd) {
        System.out.println("\nPlease select from the following");
        System.out.println("\tn to Enter the number");
        System.out.println("\ts to Show numbers by keyword ");
        System.out.println("\tp to Show all numbers ");
        System.out.println("\tc to Close the Phone book");
        System.out.print("> ");
        String input = kbd.nextLine();
        Choice choice = null;
        if (!input.isEmpty()
                && choices.contains(input.toLowerCase())
                && ((choice = Choice.getChoice(input.toLowerCase().charAt(0))) != null)) {
            return choice;
        }
        System.out.println("ERR: INVALID ENTRY. TRY AGAIN");
        return getChoice(kbd);
    }

    private static PhoneEntry getPhoneEntry(Scanner kbd) {
        System.out.print("Type contact name: ");
        String name = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Type phone number: ");
        String number = kbd.nextLine();
        try {
            return new PhoneEntry(name, number);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println("\nERR: WRONG ENTRY");
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void print(Set<PhoneEntry> entries) {
        System.out.println("\nPHONE NUMBERS\n");
        entries.stream().forEach(entry -> {
            System.out.printf("Name: %s%nPhone: %s%n%n",
                    entry.getName(), entry.getNumber());
        });
    }

    private static Set<PhoneEntry> readEntries(Set<PhoneEntry> entries, Scanner kbd) {
        System.out.print("Type keyword: ");
        return entries.stream().filter(entry
                    -> entry.nameContainsIgnoreCase(kbd.nextLine()))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! This looks really advanced, but I have my books so I will definitely be able to get a grasp of it.

Comment: Whoa man, that's like three steps ahead of where they are at the moment.

Comment: i just think they have a bad example. Examples and exercises must be just a little bit realistic. Because when you talk about phone-book, about showing a number, about adding numbers to a phone book, this is the minimum you can expect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `enterNumber;`, you have to write `enterNumber();`.

The parentheses mean: Call the method.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. I'm adding that to my notes :)